# Enforce update rule in row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table:

```
`id` - int (primary key)
`datecolumn` - datetime
`name` - varchar
```

In my application, I want to enforce a rule that the name column can't be updated if the current date and time are past the `datecolumn` field's value. Currently, I'm querying the database for the value for each row, and then updating if the current date/time is before.

I'd like to know how to enforce this without the extra call to the database before updating. I'm updating many different rows at a time in the application, and think I'm causing performance issues because of all of the extra queries.

Comment: if what can't be updated? the primary key ?

Comment: @Drew the entire row cannot be updated.

Comment: the entire row including the PK ?

Comment: @Drew yes, every column (there are more columns, but they aren't entirely necessary to include in the question).

Comment: disregarding the PK issue (not a minor problem btw), then thereafter the row can't be updated as the `datetime` is set in stone

Comment: now on to the PK issue. You just orphaned a bunch of children out there

Comment: PK isn't the issue. I've updated my question to include a little more. I'm not updating the PK at all, I'm updating other data in the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce rules like this using a trigger.

In your case, you would want a `before update` trigger.  Something like this:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger noupdates before update on t
    for each row
begin
    if new.datecolumn > now() then
        signal sqlstate '45000' 
            set message_text := 'Too late to update row';
    end if;
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I was looking for.